# Java: upcasting to a superclass and calling function from the subclass

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have two classes, Dog and Beagle.

Class Dog has method: bark()

Class Beagle has method: bark() and hunt()

If I do

```
Dog myDog = new Beagle()
myDog.bark()
```

this calls the bark function from Beagle.
However if I say,

```
myDog.hunt()
```

Eclipse generates an error. If `myDog` is still an instance of `Beagle` (given that it calls Beagle's `bark()` function) it should still be able to call the `hunt()` function? Or if it is no longer of type `Beagle`, why would it not call Dog's `bark()` function?
I don't know how to square these two behaviours with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you're writing a function

```
void something(Dog myDog) {
  ...
}
```

What can you call on `myDog`?  You know *nothing* about what kind of `Dog` it is.  You don't know if it's a `Beagle`, or something else.  But you want to be able to pass in a `Beagle`, a `Retriever`, or any other kind of dog, and have the choice of dog species matter.  The situation is exactly the same, whether it's a method parameter or a local variable.

When you define `myDog` as having type `Dog`, you are *telling* Java to forget everything about the `myDog` object except that it is a `Dog`.  Java is doing what you told it.  It has forgotten that `myDog` has any methods other than the `bark()` from `Dog`.

The *implementation* of the `bark` method that actually gets used, however, is dependent on which actual class the object has at runtime.  That method is chosen "live" based on which actual implementation happened to get passed in.

Which methods are available to be used is decided at compile time, based on the type of the variable.  Which implementation of the method gets used is decided at runtime, based on the actual object stored in that variable, and how it was created.